# Elastic Beanstalk node.js app served through SSL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have develop an *node.js* app and successfully upload and deploy it using AWS tools and Elastic Beanstalk. My app is reachable through the url provided by EB.

I create a SSL Certification through AWS Certificate Manager and assign it from configuration menu. [Load Balancer Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tU9k.png)

When i checked [Load balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfLT2.png) and security group configuration everything looks fine but if i'm trying to get https://*myappurl*.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com i get privacy error response.

I think that this is more likely a Amazon support question but maybe someone know if i miss something.

Thanks

Comment: For what domain did you get the certificate?

Comment: I create a cert for my domain i.e. myapp.mydomain.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL certificate will be for a specific domain. It is certainly not for the `myappurl.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` domain because you don't own the domain `elasticbeanstalk.com` so there's no way you could have created a valid SSL certificate for that domain. The SSL certificate is only going to work with the custom domain you created the certificate for, and only when you have that custom domain actually pointing to your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate works as per the domain name they were generated. As per your comment you got that certificate for myapp.mydomain.io so it will not work for myappurl.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com you have to map myapp.mydomain.io to point to the EB and then your myapp.mydomain.io will serve the SSL certificate. https://myapp.mydomain.io.